# Ubuntu Desktop with Wayland won't start, only Xorg works

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, xorg, wayland

I am on Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, and have installed Gnome and Ubuntu desktops. When I try to log in with the Ubuntu on Wayland option selected, it stalls for a while and reloads the login screen. The Gnome desktop just seems to choose Xorg despite my choosing the option that just says Gnome, and not gnome on Xorg, as I can see from the output of my environment variable

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE 
x11

$ service display-manager status
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-03-23 01:44:11 CET; 1min 30s ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
  Process: 1303 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(basename $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null))" = "lightdm" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1306 (lightdm)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/lightdm.service
           ├─1306 /usr/sbin/lightdm
           └─1351 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

However I installed Weston and sway, and in both of these environments Wayland works. What do I have to do to start up the Ubuntu desktop with Wayland?

Comment: In a terminal  (`Ctrl-Alt-F2`) type `service display-manager status` for more info.

Comment: I'm getting this: https://paste2.org/KjUgVADE

Comment: Don't post unnecessary links to images of text, please. Rather, Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1127693/edit ) your post, and Copy-and-Paste. Use the `{}` formatting button.

Comment: @waltinator It wasn’t an image this time… I’ve copied the text into the question.

Comment: TQ. What's in `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`? It's starting to look like your Gnome desktop fails, and runs `X` as a fallback.

Comment: Check the logs! Login somehow (this will even work in a Ctrl-Alt-F3 session). Read `man journalctl`, and `sudo journalctl -b 0` will show you logs since boot, including your troubles.