# Partial Wayland installation

Tags: wayland

I need to set

```
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf in order to reach graphical login screen.

Without this setting, the boot process ends in a black screen with a single blinking cursor in the top left corner. I'd like to understand the root cause of this issue in order to not stay illiterate on the display protocol topic.

My CPU is from Intel and I am using Intel integrated graphics (no extra graphics card installed) - maybe this is already the dealbreaker? Intel integrated graphics not supported?

Can you please point me to relevant log files or important settings? What information do you need from me for efficient help?

- Ubuntu 19.10
- integrated Intel UHD Graphics 630 graphics card
- `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu eoan main`
  in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-cosmic.list 
  no updates available

**Update 2020-02-07**

```
stange@kalliope:~$ dpkg -l | grep [Ww]ayland
ii  libva-wayland2:amd64                       2.5.0-1                                 amd64        Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- Wayland runtime
ii  libwayland-client0:amd64                   1.17.0-1                                amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - client library
ii  libwayland-cursor0:amd64                   1.17.0-1                                amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - cursor library
ii  libwayland-egl1:amd64                      1.17.0-1                                amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - EGL library
ii  libwayland-server0:amd64                   1.17.0-1                                amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - server library
ii  xwayland                                   2:1.20.7-2ubuntu1~oibaf~e               amd64        Xwayland X server
stange@kalliope:~$
```

I think I might only have a partial / drive-by installation of Wayland. Can somone please confirm? Not sure how this happened.

But this brings me to a follow-up question: how can I prohibit future updates to overwrite my setting in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf?

I am sure I had Wayland disabled but a recent package update rolled my setting back.

Thanks to Zanna [Why do I have Wayland packages installed although my system is not using Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1023676/1040713) for pointing me to my Wayland installation.

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu Desktop with Wayland won't start, only Xorg works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127693/ubuntu-desktop-with-wayland-wont-start-only-xorg-works)